# What are The Unit of measurement

Tags: movesense

I'm building an app which analysis the step of the person that wears the sensor, and I haven't found and mention in the API or the exapmle apps for what are the unit of measurement (in the linear acceleration and angular velocity).

I believe that `timestamp` is milliseconds (correct me if I'm wrong), but what are the others?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to say here: "which analyis the step of the one that whear the sensor"?

Comment: Fixed the unclear (and very weird) sentence (sorry for that, I'm not native with english, so I sometimes write weird stuff by mistake). Hope it's more clear now. Anyway, its not relevent to my question.

Comment: Since your question doesn't mention which device, whose API, what OS or language, or what data types, I was hoping knowing what you were trying to do would provide a clue.

Comment: @NetMage He tagged it as "Movesense", so it is a movesense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time Api returns data in uS

> $ wbcmd --port com9 --op get --path Time
>   {
>     "response": 200,
>     "responsestring": "HTTP_CODE_OK",
>     "operation": "get",
>     "uri": "/net/ECKIB9870DA4/Time",
>     "content": 1420070440653000,
>     "querytimems": 26,
>     "querytimens": 26918122
>   }

But Timestamp for Acc goes from the LSM6DS3 chip and it is in mS.

> $ wbcmd --port com9 --op subscribe --path Meas/Acc/13
>   /net/ECKIB9870DA4/Meas/Acc/13::onSubscribeResult
>     Subscribed and listening for notifications. Press ESC to stop:
>
> @191 { {
>     "Timestamp": 158,
>     "ArrayAcc": [
>       {
>         "x": -0.07657305896282196,
>         "y": -0.66044265031814575,
>         "z": 9.9186038970947266
>       }
>     ]
>   } }
>
> @255 { {
>     "Timestamp": 235,
>     "ArrayAcc": [
>       {
>         "x": -0.11485958844423294,
>         "y": -0.64129936695098877,
>         "z": 9.9377470016479492
>       }
>     ]
>   } }
>
> @383 { {
>     "Timestamp": 312,
>     "ArrayAcc": [
>       {
>         "x": -0.052643977105617523,
>         "y": -0.6341206431388855,
>         "z": 9.9329614639282227
>       }
>     ]
>   } }

You have to know that LSM chip doesn't have any good clock. So real timestamp can drift a little (depends on temperature) like +-2%.

Comment: I thanks you so much! Do you know what are the units of the linear acceleration and angular velocity?

Comment: @user3195363 Here is the best place to check:
https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/a08789c38c4ad7fed623950dc9fdb4c643dd7534/MovesenseCoreLib/resources/movesense-api/?at=master

LA: x-unit: m/s^2

Gyro: x-unit: dps (degree per second)