# Movesense Showcase App missing the API to reset Sensor timer. Can we add it?

Tags: swift, movesense

In the old demo app code, there was a SDK call to set sensor time.  But in the showcase app, that's no longer exposed or used.  Is that call deprecated? I see it in the API doc still.  Please advise on how to accomplish this.  When we record multiple sensors, it's much easier if we can set all the sensors to t=0 when processing all of the data so we know we can match the timeline up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just modify the source code of the showcase app. Instead of t=0 you have to put a valid UTC timestamp, so I'd recommend using the actual timestamp of the phone (remember to *1000 to get us from ms). The logic of syncing timestamps is explained in the other questions, e.g. [Android app dev: Finding the best way to synchronize the timestamps of two sensors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002930/android-app-dev-finding-the-best-way-to-synchronize-the-timestamps-of-two-senso?r=SearchResults&s=3|29.4155)

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: Thank you.  Will give this a shot.

Comment: user1987093 So setting the device UTC timestamp to the sensor doesn't cause the milliseconds counter to reset.  Is there not a way to trigger a reset of the ms counter on sensors?

Comment: Are you talking about the "RelativeTimestamp" that is returned from /Meas/Acc etc? That cannot be reset without resetting the sensor. UTC time can be set to a valid value and the relation is available with GET /Time/Detailed