# How to get both sensor timestamp and mobile timestamp in order to synchronise two Movesense sensors in Xcode?

Tags: gyroscope, ios-bluetooth, movesense

We are working on developing our own iOS app connecting with two Movesense sensors and fetching the acc, gyro and mag data. The app is going to be used for measurement of 8 hours, with 52 Hz. We'd like to collect both sensor time stamps and the phone time stamps, in order to make an accurate synchronisation of these two sensors. The default DFU settings seem to only give us sensor time stamps, which looks like this (example of only gyroscope data by Movesense Showcase app):

> [image: Blockquote]

Should I modify the DFU, or is it possible to just state it in Xcode when getting the data package? I have tried to go through the available DFU packages and the .apk files as listed on the Movesense website. I am personally not familiar with the DFU programming, therefore we'd like to use one existing DFU package from Movesense, which is hopefully stable for the connection and data sampling.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create your own firmware (DFU) for that. All the API's are available from the mobile phone, so just follow up the instructions given in this question & answer:

[Android app dev: Finding the best way to synchronize the timestamps of two sensors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002930/android-app-dev-finding-the-best-way-to-synchronize-the-timestamps-of-two-senso)

When recording ***using our Movesense Showcase app*** the situation is different since that app does not do multi sensor clock synchronisation. When recording with plain iOS Showcase app I would do "hit sensors together in the beginning and end of the recording" to synchronise the sensor data streams using the peak in acceleration. Then remember to treat the data streams as having different sample rates and base your analysis on the timestamps instead.